# How do I create a subfolder based on a variable in powershell?

Tags: powershell, directory

Fairly new to powershell.

I am trying to create two subfolder based on a user input variable.
These subfolders are Bookmarks and Organisers

I can create the main folder based on this variable, however all subfolders I try and create go to the root F:\ drive directory instead of being nested.

See code below

```
Import-Module NTFSSecurity
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$userloginname = Read-host -Prompt "Enter the users name"

$s2 = New-PSSession -ComputerName SERVERNAME
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {param($userloginname)New-Item -Name $userloginname -ItemType directory  -Path "f:\"} -ArgumentList $userloginname -Session $s2 **#this creates fine under F drive**
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {Set-Location  f:\$userloginname\} -Session $s2
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {param($userloginname)New-Item f:\$userloginname\Organisers -ItemType directory -force} -Session $s2 ##Doesnt nest under f:/$userloginname
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {param($userloginname)New-Item f:\$userloginname\Bookmarks -ItemType directory -force} -Session $s2 ##Doesnt nest under f:/$userloginname
```

I thought this would be fairly simple but no matter what combination or ordering it never nests under f:$userloginname

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: In the first one you pass in the variable as an argument correctly using `-ArgumentList`.  For the others you don't?  Either pass in `$userloginname` the same way using `-ArgumentList` or change to `$using:userloginname` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_variables?view=powershell-7.1#using-local-variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're only passing `$userloginname` as argument on your first call to `Invoke-Command` and not on the next invocations. In addition, the code could be simplified to do everything on your first call to `Invoke-Command`:

```
Import-Module NTFSSecurity
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$userloginname = Read-host -Prompt "Enter the users name"

$s2 = New-PSSession -ComputerName SERVERNAME

Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {
    param($userloginname)

    $dir = Join-Path 'F:' -ChildPath $userloginname

    'Organisers','Bookmarks' | ForEach-Object {
        New-Item (Join-Path $dir -ChildPath $_) -ItemType Directory -Force
    }

} -ArgumentList $userloginname -Session $s2
```

Also, as [Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68630182/how-do-i-create-a-subfolder-based-on-a-variable-in-powershell/68630298#comment121288719_68630182) pointed out in his comment, you can use `$using:userloginname` on a remote session which would simplified the code even more. See [about Remote Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_variables?view=powershell-7.1#using-local-variables).

```
$userloginname = Read-host -Prompt "Enter the users name"

$s2 = New-PSSession -ComputerName SERVERNAME

Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {

    $dir = Join-Path 'F:' -ChildPath $using:userloginname

    'Organisers','Bookmarks' | ForEach-Object {
        New-Item (Join-Path $dir -ChildPath $_) -ItemType Directory -Force
    }

} -Session $s2
```

This should also work, which would make `Invoke-Command` not needed in this particular case:

```
$server = '\\SERVERNAME\F$'
$userloginname = Read-host -Prompt "Enter the users name"
$dir = Join-Path $server -ChildPath $userloginname

'Organisers','Bookmarks' | ForEach-Object {
    New-Item -Path (Join-Path $dir -ChildPath $_) -ItemType Directory -Force
}
```